# How to add ListView to MapView from the xml resource?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

How to add ListView to MapView from the xml resource ?

In order words, I am trying to make a screen contains google MapView and ListView.

Because impossible to extends 2 Activitys' (ListActivity & MapActvity), I am trying to add a ListView(It is created from xml resource) to MapView.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `MapActivity` that has, in its layout, a `MapView` and a `ListView`. Use `findViewById()` to get to the `ListView` in order to be able to work with it. You do not need to use `ListActivity` to work with a `ListView`, but (AFAIK) you do need to use `MapActivity` to work with a `MapView`.